# Laravel Timezone UTC but got a London

Tags: laravel, timezone

I have a question

In Laravel config/app `timezone = UTC` 
But my localhost is in Japan, `created_at time is London

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: `timezone` is `UTC. I am in Japan why did I get London `timezone` . At 11:00 AM, created_at value is 3:00 AM.

Answer (score 2):

I not sure that I have understood your question but... you are saying your locale config is UTC therefore you application runs with the correct configured timezone.

If you want to set a different timezone you should change it in config/app.php.

Check all available timezones in php: http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You can set your timezone in laravel config/app like this

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Tokyo'
```

This should solve your problem. With reference to http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Regards.